# Firebase 3-way data binding with ControllerAs syntax

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I'm tring to get 3-way data binding with firebase and angularfire. You can see what I've got in Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/RGA4jZK3Y6n4RkPCHK37

**app.js**:

```
angular.module('ideaBattle', ["firebase"]);
```

**services**:

```
angular
    .module('ideaBattle')
    .constant('FBURL', 'https://ideabattle.firebaseio.com/')
    .service('Ref', ['FBURL', Firebase])
    .factory('dataBank', function(Ref, $firebase) {
        return $firebase(Ref).$asArray();
    });
```

**controller**:

```
angular
    .module('ideaBattle')
    .controller('ideaListCtrl', displayIdeas);

displayIdeas.$inject = ['dataBank'];
function displayIdeas(dataBank){
    var vm = this;
    vm.ideas = dataBank;

    vm.upVote = function(idea){
        vm.ideas[idea.id].votes++;
    };
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<div ng-controller="ideaListCtrl as vm">
    <div ng-repeat="idea in vm.ideas | orderBy: '-votes'">
        <div>
            <h2>{{idea.name}}</h2>
            <p>{{idea.desc|limitTo: 190}}</p>
            <span class="btn" ng-click="vm.upVote(idea)">Vote! <span class="badge"> {{idea.votes}}</span></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Plunker version: http://plnkr.co/edit/RGA4jZK3Y6n4RkPCHK37

What it does, it gets the data from firebase and displays it correctly, but when I push the button to call upVote function it only updates locally. I know why it only works locally, but I don't know how to make it also update in firebase.

I've tried with $bindTo, but from what I understand it requires $scope to work, and I'm trying to use "Controller as vm" pattern without injecting $scope.

Can anybody tell me how to bite that?

Comment: did you call $save(), [see the documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebasearray-saverecordorindex)

Comment: From what I understand $save is a function that I need to call everytime I want firebase to update. That's not really the approach I want. I'd like more of a "set-it-and-forget-it" 3-way data binding so that every change made to the data locally would be reflected in firebase. I know it can be done easiliy using $bindTo($scope, "data") method, but I don't want to use the $scope at all, hence my question, how to do it keeping this pattern.

Comment: vm.ideas[idea.id].votes++;
vm.ideas.$save(idea.id).then(function(ref) {
  ref.key() === vm-ideas[idea.id].$id; // true
});

Comment: This works - ofcourse, but it's still not a 3-way data binding - just  function updating firebase. I would need to call it everywhere I make a change, but I want it to be automatic, just like it is locally (2-way data binding). I know it can be done. I cannot figure out how.

Comment: Well everything is just a function. Try [extending Array factory](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-extending-the-factories-firebasearrayextendfactory), to keep things DRY

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### tl;dr; — 3-way data-binding does not work with ControllerAs syntax. The `bindTo` method requires `$scope`.

You can use AngularFire with ControllerAs syntax, but you can't use it with ControllerAs with `$bindTo`.

`$bindTo` has a hard dependency on `$scope` and it will break without it.

If you want an example of using AngularFire with ControllerAs syntax, check out **[this Plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/A4YNUT?p=preview)**.

```
  angular.module('app', ['firebase'])

  // constant for the Firebase we're using
  .constant('FBURL', 'https://<your-firebase>.firebaseio.com/todos')

  // return the Firebase ref as a service
  .service('Ref', ['FBURL', Firebase])

  // return the Todos from Firebase by returning the
  // array from the factory 
  .factory('Todos', function(Ref, $firebase) {
    return $firebase(Ref).$asArray();
  })

  // inject the Todos and assign them to "this"
  // for the ControllerAs syntax
  .controller('MainCtrl', function(Todos) {
    this.todos = Todos;
  });
```

Comment: If you take a look at my code, you can see, this plunker you mentioned is exactly the one I build mine upon. But the problem still stands. I don't know how to make it use 3-way data binding.

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, *you can't* use AngularFire and ControllerAs syntax with 3-way data-binding. `bindTo` relies on `$scope`, which goes against the grain of the ControllerAs syntax.

Comment: Is bindTo the only way to get 3-way data binding? Isn't there some way around it?

Comment: The `bindTo` method sets up automatic 3-way data-binding. However, you can still create a Firebase array like in the example above. Whenever a change happens you can manually add/update the array. The change will update Firebase, which will automatically update the array and rebind your template.

Answer (score 5):

[John Papa talks](http://www.johnpapa.net/angularjss-controller-as-and-the-vm-variable/) about one of the purposes of using the var `vm = this;` syntax instead of `$scope` in every controller is to make the use of `$scope` a conscious choice. In this case we need to include $scope.

I took David East's plunkr in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27368048/356620) and fiddled with it a bit. It isn't *perfect* because it depends on the controllerAs value being 'vm'.

http://plnkr.co/edit/vLLaa7QJvfryYRD7cZvO?p=preview

```
  .controller('MainCtrl', function(Todos, $scope) { /* Add $scope */
    var vm = this;

    vm.todos = Todos.all();

    vm.lonelyTodo = Todos.get('-JeNOtYPv7AZmVAoZ1bu');
    vm.lonelyTodo.$bindTo($scope, 'vm.lonelyTodo'); /* Add three way binding */
  });
```

Comment: This is a great workaround especially if you're using TypeScript which promotes using classes with ControllerAs.

Comment: I think this is the answer people are looking for and it's also done the right way.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a few clarifications comments to the response above using ES6/JS2015 systax as an example.

```
export class SomeController {
  constructor($firebaseObject, $scope) {
  'ngInject';    

  //using the firebase SDK 3.0 
  let obj = $firebaseObject(firebase.database().ref().child('someKey'));

  // To make the data available in the DOM, assign it to
  // 'this.data' accessible from DOM as $ctrl.data
  this.data = obj;

  // For three-way data bindings, you will still need to inject '$scope'
  // but you can alias your controller on $scope
  obj.$bindTo($scope, '$ctrl.data');

  // Why does this work? 
  // This works because angular 1x puts controllerAs
  // on top of $scope. So '$scope.$ctrl.data' is the same as 'this.data'.
  // Note: $ctrl is the default controllerAs syntax if not specified,
  // just change $ctrl to your defined controllerAs ailias if 
  // specified. 
  }
}
```