# AngularFire 3-way-binding without $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding, angularfire

So I'm reading the AngularFire documentation on 3-way-binding and am trying to do it without $scope. This is my controller:

```
angular.module('APP', ['firebase']).controller('Ctrl', Ctrl);

    Ctrl.$inject = ['$firebaseObject'];

    function Ctrl($firebaseObject) {
        var vm = this;

        var ref = new Firebase('https://testfirebase23.firebaseio.com/');
        var syncObj = $firebaseObject(ref);

        syncObj.$bindTo(vm, 'data');
    }
```

When I run the code I get this error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at e (angularfire.min.js:12)
    at Object.e.bindTo (angularfire.min.js:12)
    at angularfire.min.js:12
    at processQueue (angular.js:13248)
    at angular.js:13264
    at Scope.$eval (angular.js:14466)
    at Scope.$digest (angular.js:14282)
    at Scope.$apply (angular.js:14571)
    at angular.js:16308
    at completeOutstandingRequest (angular.js:4924)
```

I don't understand the error. Is there a way to 3-way-bind an object or array to tbe controller without $scope?

Comment: Try running in non  minified mode, see if the error persists.

Comment: I haven't minified anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$bindTo` of firebase will never work with `controllerAs` syntax,
You could achieve this by assign you `firebase` object directly to any controller context variable.

**Code**

```
var ref = new Firebase('https://testfirebase23.firebaseio.com/');
vm.syncObj = $firebaseObject(ref); //this will ensure your binding will work
```

Refer [**this SO answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27368048/2435473) to

Comment: `var ref = new Firebase('https://testfirebase23.firebaseio.com/');
vm.syncObj = $firebaseObject(ref); //this will ensure your binding will work`

This is what I have, but I would have to update the syncObj with $.save() right?

Comment: yes it would update the syncObj binding..Do upvote if it does helped you.

Answer (score 0):

I recently started studying about the AngularFire as I'm new to this, while doing R&D I got through this:
$bindTo() had a strong dependency on the $scope. 
For the reference you can see this [Firebase 3-way data binding with ControllerAs syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27367289/firebase-3-way-data-binding-with-controlleras-syntax).